# how to handle combobox "onchange" event?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a `HashMap<Date, List<Service>>` and i display dates in combobox in my **index.scala.html**

```
<select name="Dates" >
    @for((k,v) <- dates) {
        <option >@k</option>
    }
 </select>
```

to display `List<Service>` i have this code in **index.scala.html**

```
@getServices(date: String) = {
<table class="computers zebra-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Service name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th colspan="2">Counter</th>
        <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>start</th>
        <th>end</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for(s <- dates.get(utility.MonthYear.getUkrDate(date))) {
    <tr>
        <td>@s.getName</td>
        <td>@s.getPriceString</td>
        <td>@s.getFromCounterString</td>
        <td>@s.getToCounterString</td>
        <td>@s.getNote</td>
    </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

}

I need to know server-side, what item was selected from combobox.

So, question, how do can i display List acording to my date on `"onchange"` event in my combobox?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Dates" >
    @for((k,v) <- dates) {
        <option value="@k">@k</option>
    }
 </select>
```